# JSTL import scope attributes

Tags: jsp, import, scope, jstl

I'm using JSTL to import a form from my main page.

```
<c:import url = "/import/form/registerForm.jsp" />
```

The main page receives a attribute named registerError from a Servlet. This attribute is available from my main page but it disappears in my registerForm.jsp file

```
<c:if test = "${!empty registerError}">
    <div id = "error">
        <p><c:out value="${registerError}" /></p>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

I've red that the attributes can be passed through import but as a GET method. Is there any other way to manage this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
<jsp:include page="/import/form/registerForm.jsp"/>
```

`<c:import>` allows getting a resource from anywhere (including resources external to the webapp), and thus generates a new request, different from the original one, to get the resource. `<jsp:include>` uses the request dispatcher, and the same request is thus used.

Comment: Ok thanks! But is <jsp:include> a good practice today? Or is there other alternatives to this solution?